# Filter associative rows based on a column value where the rows are in a specific subarray of a 3d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I am trying array_filter() to remove nested arrays that are blank but I only get back all the nested arrays. I know I am using it wrong but see a similar case like what I am trying.

Here is the data:

```
[
    'ticket_number' => 'sdfsdfsdf 2',
    'strategy_id' => '5',
    'journal_entries_strategy_conditions' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => ''
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '1'
        ]
    ],
    'timeframe' => '',
]
```

I want to remove `'strategies_condition_id' => ''` but all I get back is

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'strategies_condition_id' => ''
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'strategies_condition_id' => '1'
    ]
]
```

I think I am using it right:

```
debug(
  array_filter(
    $data['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'], 
    function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a nested array you need to go the longer route and use array_column then replace the array subarray with an intersect of the keys.

```
$filtered = array_filter(array_column($arr['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'], 'strategies_condition_id'));

$arr['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'] = array_intersect_key($arr['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'], $filtered);

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/iC66a
It can be made even less readable by making it a one liner.

And you don't need the custom function for this.
Array_filter removes '' and null values by default.

Answer (score 2):

The `$value` you are passing to the filtering function is an associative array too.

So you have to check the "*value of the value*", using `current()` makes the filtering function agnostic of the key name, making this code portable if needed. I named the function argument as `$entry` to avoid confusion:

```
$data= [
    'ticket_number' => 'sdfsdfsdf 2',
    'strategy_id' => '5',
    'journal_entries_strategy_conditions' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => ''
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '1'
        ]
    ],
    'timeframe' => '',
];


var_dump(
    array_filter(
        $data['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'],
        function($entry) {
            $value = current($entry);
            return !is_null($value) && $value !== '';
        }
    )
);
```

The result is:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["strategies_condition_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for the entire array with `'strategies_condition_id' => ''` removed

Comment: @KeithPower Your question is passing only that key to the filtering function .. I made the PoC on your guidance ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you have an associative array inside filtering array technically it is not empty, that is why your code does not work.

If you want specified key (assume that key **does** exist) inside filtering array not empty just pass that key value like follows:

```
$data = [
        (int) 0 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '',
            'test' => '',
            'asd' => 'asd'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '1'
        ]
    ];
$key = 'strategies_condition_id';
$result = array_filter($data, function($value) use ($key) {dump($value); return !is_null($value[$key]) && $value[$key] !== ''; });
```

**Output:**

```
array:1 [
  1 => array:1 [
    "strategies_condition_id" => "1"
  ]
]
```

Array `0` was skipped because it had `strategies_condition_id` key empty.

Also another simple approach to check if you have any empty value inside filtering array:

```
$data = [
        (int) 0 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '',
            'test' => 'test'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '1'
        ],
        (int) 2 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '2',
            'test' => ''
        ]
    ];
array_filter($data, function($value) { return !in_array('',$value); });
```

**Output:**

```
array:1 [
  1 => array:1 [
    "strategies_condition_id" => "1"
  ]
]
```

Comment: @Andreas I just assumed that `data` is `$arr['journal_entries_strategy_conditions']` as mentioned in question `debug()` (edited answer), but even if we take raw array we can `use($key1, $key2 ... $keyN)` again if we sure that keys does exist, if not just add additional checks inside callback. I just gave some examples so asker could choose and modify

Answer (score 0):

Using a single `array_filter()` on the specific first level element will do the job.  Inside the function's callback, there is no need for any function calls; just access the targeted associative subarray value and check if it is truthy.  This is as simple as it gets with functional style coding.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/L7elQ))

```
$array['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'] = array_filter(
    $array['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'],
    fn($row) => $row['strategies_condition_id']
);
```

---

The equivalent with a classic loop can use `unset()` conditionally. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9CiWa))

```
foreach ($array['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'] as $i => $row) {
    if (!$row['strategies_condition_id']) {
        unset($array['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'][$i]);
    }
}
```

Or if you wish to have a reindexed subarray, `array_splice()` is helpful. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/41LK2))

```
foreach ($array['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'] as $i => $row) {
    if (!$row['strategies_condition_id']) {
        array_splice($array['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'], $i, 1);
    }
}
```